# Problem with Style in a Plot

Tags: plotting, legending

I would like to simply plot a density function $f_1$ and I would like to put a legend but I cannot do it as I wish. The problem is simple but I spent alot of time and couldnt solve it. I will be happy for your help. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
f1[y_] := (PDF[NormalDistribution[1, 1], y]); 

Plot[{f1[y]}, {y, -5, 5}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Style[Subscript[OverHat[g], 1] (\[Alpha] = 100), FontSize -> 21]}, LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 2, FrameStyle -> LightGray] &), BaseStyle -> 18], {Right, Top}], PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {Style[y, FontSize -> 21], Style[Subscript[OverHat[g], 1], FontSize -> 21]}, BaseStyle -> 18, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03]]
```

The probem is at this point

```
Style[Subscript[OverHat[g], 1] (\[Alpha] = 100),
```

First I dont see any $\alpha$ and second the term  ([Alpha] = 100) is coming in front of Subscript[OverHat[g], 1], which is annoying me alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[{f1[y]}, {y, -5, 5}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Style[
      Row[{Subscript[OverHat[g], 1] , "(\[Alpha]=100)"}], 
      FontSize -> 21]}, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 2, 
        FrameStyle -> LightGray] &), BaseStyle -> 18], {Right, Top}], 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style[y, FontSize -> 21], 
   Style[Subscript[OverHat[g], 1], FontSize -> 21]}, BaseStyle -> 18, 
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.03]]
```

[image]

You could also use

```
Style[HoldForm[Subscript[OverHat[g], 1] (\[Alpha] = 100)],  FontSize -> 21]
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. It solved my problem completely. I wonder one more little thing if you dont mind. If I have say $4$ legend terms and I want to make a $2\times 2$ legend. How can I do it? I mean in the default case it lists $4$ items one under the other one. Thanks.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören - use the `LegendLayout` option to `LineLegend`, eg `LineLegend[63, Range[4], LegendLayout -> {"Row", 2}]`

Comment: @seyhmus, can you add a simple example of the 4 terms to your post?  ... I see Verbeia answered  your question already.

Comment: @Verbeia thank you very much for pointing out. Very good moderator)